# Two select query at a time python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I want to calculate distance between two points. For that for each point in one table i have to calculate distance with all the other point in another table in same database. I am using python for that but I am not able to execute two query at a time.

```
import mysql.connector
from haversine import haversine

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='xxxxx',passwd='xxxxxx',db='xxxxxx')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor2 = cnx.cursor()

query = ("select longitude,latitude from roadData limit 5")
cursor.execute(query)

query2=("SELECT geo_coordinates_latitude, geo_coordinates_longitude from tweetmelbourne limit 2")
cursor2.execute(query2)

for (longitude,latitude) in cursor:
    print longitude
    print latitude
    for (geo_coordinates_longitude,geo_coordinates_latitude) in cursor2:
        print geo_coordinates_longitude
        print geo_coordinates_latitude


cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

But, I am getting error for second query execution

> InternalError: Unread result found.

I tried buffer=true for cursor but still same error.
And also is it efficient to do like this or any other better way.

Answer (score 0):

One trick you could use here would be to cross join the two tables together:

```
SELECT t1.longitude,
       t1.latitude,
       t2.geo_coordinates_latitude,
       t2.geo_coordinates_longitude
FROM
(
    SELECT longitude, latitude
    FROM roadData
    LIMIT 5
) t1
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT geo_coordinates_latitude, geo_coordinates_longitude
    FROM tweetmelbourne
    LIMIT 2
) t2
```

This should work because the way you iterate over the result set in your Python code resembles a cross join.  In this case, using the above query you would only need to iterate once over the entire result set.

Comment: Hi Tim I get what you are saying but I have 4 Gb of data so CrOSS Join is not beneficial and it is slow. If I acn do row-wise I acn store the result on the run. For cross join first you have to map and then it will calculate.

Comment: The method used to connect two tables in SQL is a join (well, also a union, but won't work here).  If you can't join, and your current method won't work, then what options have you left?

Comment: I want to get rowwise data and then do rowise cross join with all entries of other table and filtering based on distance condition store in another table.